# .indexOf not returning expected value on node.js

Tags: node.js

i was write code for node js and it works fine , except for this if statement:

```
if ( req.url.indexOf( '/search=') !== -1 ){
  req.url.replace('/search=' , '');
  console.log(req.url);
  return;
```

}

When i write in the browser "/search=test" instead of returning "test" , it returns "/search=test", basicly the node js do not pas trough this if.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `req.query.search` attributes. It will return to you the `test` string. If you would like to use the query params from a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string. So, you should define new variable and pass replaced value inside that. Like this below code.

```
if ( req.url.indexOf( '/search=') !== -1 ){
    const url = req.url.replace('/search=' , '');
    console.log(url);
    return url;
}
```

Comment: Just as an improvement, it might be worth pointing out that the reason for this behaviour is `replace()` not operating in-place (as one might expect), but instead returning a new String.

Comment: thanks i thinked that it will remove the part that i wanted from the string